# How to remove Time Zone from datetime?

Tags: python-2.7, mako, openedx

Im trying to display course_start_date with time but without Time Zone (11 Jan 2020 15:00)

I was tried changing data-format="shortDate" (display only date) and removing z from course_date_string = course_start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') but without success.

Expected output: 1 Jan 2020 15:00

```py
<%block name="course_about_important_dates">
  <ol class="important-dates">
    <li class="important-dates-item">
      <span class="icon fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span><p class="important-dates-item-title">${_("Course Number")}</p><span class="important-dates-item-text course-number">${course.display_number_with_default}
      </span>
    </li>
    % if not course.start_date_is_still_default:
      <%
        course_start_date = course.advertised_start or course.start
      %>
      <li class="important-dates-item">
        <span class="icon fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <p class="important-dates-item-title">${_("Classes Start")}</p>
        % if isinstance(course_start_date, string_types):
          <span class="important-dates-item-text start-date"> 
            ${course_start_date}
          </span>
        % else:
          <%
            course_date_string = course_start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
          %>
          <span class="important-dates-item-text start-date localized_datetime" data-format="ISODate" data-datetime="${course_date_string}" data-language="${LANGUAGE_CODE}"></span>
        % endif
      </li>
    % endif
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the date? "1 Jan 2020 15:00"?

Comment: yes, sorry, i forgot to specify this in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the right formatting string to achieve `1 Jan 2020 15:00`:

`%d` for the day, `%b` for the month shortname, `%Y` for the full year, `%H` for the hour and `%M` for the minute.

Below, a snippet with an example:

```py
# [Code]
from datetime import datetime
course_start_date = datetime.now()
print(course_start_date.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M'))
# [Output]
"23 Sep 2019 18:10"
```